# SQL query to find the records which are interleaved

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table which has 3 columns `id, start_time, end_time` where `start_time` and `end_time` are of `DATE` type.

How do I write a query which will group records whose processing times are interleaved.

For example,

```
id    start_time         end_time
---------------------------------------------------------
1   25/07/2013 10:30:00  25/07/2013 11:30:00
2   25/07/2013 11:00:00  25/07/2013 12:00:00
3   25/07/2013 11:15:00  25/07/2013 12:30:00
4   25/07/2013 14:30:00  25/07/2013 15:30:00
5   25/07/2013 10:30:00  25/07/2013 11:15:00
6   25/07/2013 13:30:00  25/07/2013 14:45:00
```

Here, `id 1,2,3,5` are interleaved and `4,6` and interleaved.

How can I achieve this?

I'm using Oracle 11g.

Comment: what is the desiered result output of the query?

Comment: You have table with 3 columns- so, your question about `ORDER`?

Comment: So, you want to get as result all the id couples that are interleaving?

Comment: There may be a more "appropriate" way to fulfill your _actual_ desire. Can you share your _reason_ of the question? In the sample data you provided, each task lasts around 1 hour, so simply `ORDER BY start_time` will give you a high chance that "adjacent records" are interleaving.

Answer (score 1):

There is an undocumented function in oracle called [`overlaps`](http://www.orafaq.com/node/2067)

```
select * 
from t1 , t2 
where (t1.start_time , t1.end_time) overlaps (t2.start_time , t2.end_time)
```

**I strongly suggest not to use undocumented features** 
but it's still cool to know it !

Comment: Learn somethin' new ever' day.  I can confirm (via [this SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a3670/2)) that this feature is still present in 11g2.

Answer (score 0):

Is this one you looking for

```
SELECT  id ,           
    DATEDIFF(mi,start_time ,end_time+1) as interval
FROM table A 
ORDER BY (DATEDIFF(mi,start_time ,end_time+1))
```

Comment: `datediff` is not a valid Oracle function

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach where you identify each record that is *not* interleaved with another one that has an earlier `start_time`.  It is the "start" of an interleave group.  Then, take the cumulative sum of this count, and that identifies each group.

You can do this with a self join and window functions:

```
select t.*,
       count(starts.id) over (order by t.start_time) as InterleaveGrouping
from t left outer join
     (select distinct t.id
      from t left outer join
           t tprev
           on t.start_time < tprev.end_time and t.end_time > tprev.start_time and
              t.start_time > tprev.start_time
      where tprev.id is null
     ) starts
     on t.id = starts.id;
```

If you want information about the groups, you can then use `group by InterleaveGrouping`.

Comment: Hm, your query would seem to be missing a join condition for the outer join. `ORA-00905: missing keyword`.

Answer (score 0):

Following is what you are looking for:

> Sybase

```
select distinct 
    t1.*
from
    table_name t1,
    table_name t2
where
    datediff(ss,t2.start_time,t1.start_time) > 0
and datediff(ss,t2.end_time,t1.start_time) < 0
union
select distinct 
    t1.*
from
    table_name t1,
    table_name t2
where
    datediff(ss,t2.start_time,t1.start_time) < 0
and datediff(ss,t2.start_time,t1.end_time) > 0
order by t1.start_time
```

> Oracle:

```
select distinct 
    t1.*
from
    table_name t1,
    table_name t2
where
    t1.START_DATE - t2.START_DATE > 0
and t1.START_DATE - t2.END_DATE < 0
union
select distinct 
    t1.*
from
    table_name t1,
    table_name t2
where
    t1.START_DATE - t2.START_DATE < 0
and t1.END_DATE - t2.START_DATE > 0
```

The above answer assume the columns as DATE datatype, if they aren't use TO_DATE() function to convert the same. I hope this help.

Comment: You can test with [this SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7cf21). Doesn't quite work "out of the box".

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, combining common table expressions with a recursive query at the end;

```
WITH cte1 AS (
  SELECT a."id" id, a."start_time" start_time, a."end_time" end_time,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a."start_time", a."end_time") rn
  FROM Table1 a
), cte2 AS (
  SELECT id, start_time, end_time, 
    (SELECT MIN(id) FROM cte1 b WHERE b.id<a.id AND a.start_time<b.end_time) overlap
  FROM cte1 a
), cte3 (id, overlap) AS (
   SELECT id, id overlap FROM cte2 WHERE overlap IS NULL
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT nplus.id, n.overlap
   FROM cte2 nplus
   JOIN cte3 n
     ON nplus.overlap = n.id
)
SELECT * FROM cte3;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/da810/1).

EDIT: After reflecting a bit, this is simpler :)

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*, 
    COUNT(DECODE(t2.id, NULL, 0, NULL)) 
     OVER (ORDER BY t1.start_time, t1.end_time) igroup
FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN Table1 t2 
  ON t1.id <> t2.id AND t1.start_time >= t2.start_time 
                    AND t1.start_time <  t2.end_time
ORDER BY t1.start_time, t1.end_time
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/30a65/1).